# PayPal Checkout Integration with Smart Payment Buttons

Tags: php, paypal-sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk, codeigniter-4

I'm currently working with the PHP framework Codeigniter 4.0.4 and trying to add the PayPal Checkout Intergration with Smart Payment Buttons.

I used the PayPal API as an example, but I always get an error message when I try to create an order.
When I click on the PayPal button to pay, the window opens for 1-2 seconds and then closes again immediately.

Console error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0

Error: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
    at $t.error (https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=Af6lu4xavdi1_e_hEFLWQxUj48hq0bndx7o3RGgwNWuChHmenioXFLMnTOKt912F6zmftF1Siv9WsfCp&disable-funding=credit,card:2:59754)
    at Object.<anonymous> (https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=Af6lu4xavdi1_e_hEFLWQxUj48hq0bndx7o3RGgwNWuChHmenioXFLMnTOKt912F6zmftF1Siv9WsfCp&disable-funding=credit,card:2:67521)
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at o (https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=Af6lu4xavdi1_e_hEFLWQxUj48hq0bndx7o3RGgwNWuChHmenioXFLMnTOKt912F6zmftF1Siv9WsfCp&disable-funding=credit,card:2:67380)
    at cr (https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=Af6lu4xavdi1_e_hEFLWQxUj48hq0bndx7o3RGgwNWuChHmenioXFLMnTOKt912F6zmftF1Siv9WsfCp&disable-funding=credit,card:2:67533)
    at Cr.u.on (https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=Af6lu4xavdi1_e_hEFLWQxUj48hq0bndx7o3RGgwNWuChHmenioXFLMnTOKt912F6zmftF1Siv9WsfCp&disable-funding=credit,card:2:72204)
    at Cr (https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=Af6lu4xavdi1_e_hEFLWQxUj48hq0bndx7o3RGgwNWuChHmenioXFLMnTOKt912F6zmftF1Siv9WsfCp&disable-funding=credit,card:2:72341)
    at https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=Af6lu4xavdi1_e_hEFLWQxUj48hq0bndx7o3RGgwNWuChHmenioXFLMnTOKt912F6zmftF1Siv9WsfCp&disable-funding=credit,card:2:78460
    at Function.n.try (https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=Af6lu4xavdi1_e_hEFLWQxUj48hq0bndx7o3RGgwNWuChHmenioXFLMnTOKt912F6zmftF1Siv9WsfCp&disable-funding=credit,card:2:14069)
    at https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=Af6lu4xavdi1_e_hEFLWQxUj48hq0bndx7o3RGgwNWuChHmenioXFLMnTOKt912F6zmftF1Siv9WsfCp&disable-funding=credit,card:2:78257
```

Serverside:

```
$clientId = getenv('paypal.CLIENT_ID');
$clientSecret = getenv('paypal.CLIENT_SECRET');

$environment = new SandboxEnvironment($clientId, $clientSecret);
$client = new PayPalHttpClient($environment);

$request = new OrdersCreateRequest();
$request->prefer('return=representation');
$request->body = [
    "intent" => "CAPTURE",
    "purchase_units" => [[
        'reference_id' => '123',
        "amount" => [
            "value" => 10,
            "currency_code" => "USD"
        ]
    ]],
    "application_context" => [
        "cancel_url" => base_url() . "/checkout",
        "return_url" => base_url() . "/checkout"
    ]
];

try {
    $response = $client->execute($request);
    return json_encode($response);
} catch (HttpException $ex) {
    echo $ex->statusCode;
    print_r($ex->getMessage());
}
```

Clientside:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    paypal.Buttons({
        env: 'sandbox',

        style: {
            layout: 'vertical',
            size: 'responsive',
            shape: 'pill',
            color: 'blue',
            label: 'pay'
        },

        createOrder: function() {
            return fetch('/checkout/paypal', {
                method: 'post',
                headers: {
                    'content-type': 'application/json'
                }
            }).then(function(response) {
                return response.json();
            }).then(function(resJson) {
                return resJson.result.id;
            });
        }
    }).render('#paypal-button-container');
</script>
```

Comment: Its not returning json. Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0 means its returning html because < is <html>

Comment: But why? The /checkout/paypal is returning a json

Comment: are you sure its post request not get? check routes

Comment: Fetch finished loading: POST "http://localhost:8080/checkout/paypal".

Comment: console.log(response.json()); and resJson to make sure its returning that

Comment: `Promise {<pending>}
__proto__: Promise
[[PromiseState]]: "rejected"
[[PromiseResult]]: SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
message: "Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0"
stack: "SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0"
__proto__: Error #Edit That's the output of response.json

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    paypal.Buttons({
        env: 'sandbox',

        style: {
            layout: 'vertical',
            size: 'responsive',
            shape: 'pill',
            color: 'blue',
            label: 'pay'
        },

        createOrder: function() {
            return fetch('/checkout/paypal', {
                method: 'post',
                headers: {
                    'content-type': 'application/json'
                }
            }).then(function(response) {
                console.log(response);
          
            });
        }
    }).render('#paypal-button-container');
</script>
```

what will return on Console

Comment: click_initiate_payment_reject {err: "Error: Expected an order id to be passed↵    at ht…tF1Siv9WsfCp&disable-funding=credit,card:2:10596)", timestamp: "1602606170399", referer: "www.sandbox.paypal.com", sdkCorrelationID: "ffdd74d018833", sessionID: "39b2cf6396_mty6mtq6mjc", …}

Comment: Ah, problem is in php part, not on client. Also check this similar : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57197907/paypal-expected-an-order-id-to-be-passed

Comment: The response is wrong, the second .then is there for the orderId but it's not going into it since the response gives me an error. I have already looked into the PayPal documentation several times but do not understand why the error occurs ...